# org.springframework.http.InvalidMediaTypeException in Spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

My spring boot application was running fine. Suddenly I am facing an strange issue.

Below is the StackTrace:

```
 Inside Global Exception Handler. Exception caught is {}
 org.springframework.http.InvalidMediaTypeException: Invalid mime type "text/xml; charset=UTF-8,application/xml": UTF-8,application/xml
at org.springframework.http.MediaType.parseMediaType(MediaType.java:452) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.getContentType(HttpHeaders.java:760) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.getContentType(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:115) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:85) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:662) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:620) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:387) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at com.airtelbank.insurance.utils.RestUtils.postXmlRequest(RestUtils.java:100) ~[classes!/:1.0.5]
at com.airtelbank.insurance.utils.RestUtils.postXmlRequest(RestUtils.java:122) ~[classes!/:1.0.5]
at com.airtelbank.insurance.service.impl.vehicle.IDVServiceImpl.getIDVValue(IDVServiceImpl.java:116) ~[classes!/:1.0.5]
at com.airtelbank.insurance.controller.vehicle.GIController.checkIDV(GIController.java:198) ~[classes!/:1.0.5]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
```

Request Mapping in controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "v1/test", method = RequestMethod.GET, consumer ="application/json",produces = {"application/JSON"})
```

Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: i think this is about when you request on controller dispatcher servlet is mapping via consumer and producer type I think you need to change request mapping consumer type   maybe controller wants as a json but you sending as text / xml . I think you using postman right ?

Comment: Actually it was working fine , since last one hour i am getting this exception. It is throwing exception inside the Spring boot application when i am trying to access them

Comment: please check i have updated

Comment: You are sending XML whereas the receiving side doesn't accept XML.

Comment: You should add your basic details about your issue in question instead of comments on answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you post code you need to post your request as content-type = application/xml or text/xml

change like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test",consumer ="application/xml or text/xml", produces = {"application/json"})
```

after that change your request header side content-type as application/xml or text/xml 
then it will be fixed.And also provide method (GET ,POST)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "v1/test", method = RequestMethod.POST,consume="text/xml",produces="application/json")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<CustomObject> test(@RequestBody CustomXMLObject) {
    // do some logical things for example change to json

return new ResponseEntity<CustomObject>(convertedJsonObject,HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

request this method as post and set header content-type as text/xml

Comment: I am consuming SOAP service of third party i.e. xml request and response. I am parsing xml response from third party and sending JSON response from my service

Comment: But it is running fine at my local machine

Comment: Could you provide exact syntax , consumer is not resolvable in my code

Answer (score 0):

When you are reading the xml from 3rd party service, you should parse it correctly and have below annotation on your Rest endpoint to convert it into json.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "v1/test", method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes = {"application/json"} ,produces = {"application/json"})
```

The `produces` and `consumes` attributes specifies Type of data produced by that endpoint and type of data consumed (accepted) by that endpoint respectively.